# stylus how to implement a loop?

Tags: css, stylus

Good day. There is an object class name and the path to the icon.

```
currentProject = {'current-project': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'composition-project': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'room': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'terms': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'documents': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'command': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'contact': '../../sprites/123.png'}
```

How to get the result?

```
 &__current-project: 
    background-image: url('../../sprites/123.png')
 &__room 
    background-image: url('../../sprites/123.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stylus use the iteration syntax **for <val-name> [, <key-name>] in <expression>**

```
currentProject = {'current-project': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'composition-project': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'room': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'terms': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'documents': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'command': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'contact': '../../sprites/123.png'}

div                 
  for k, v in currentProject
    &_{k}
      background-image v
```

The output should be

```
div_current-project {
  background-image: '../../sprites/123.png';
}
...
```

Comment: also can use a mixin to use any selector you want: [demo](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=currentProject%20%3D%20%7B%27current-project%27%3A%20%27..%2F..%2Fsprites%2F123.png%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27room%27%3A%20%27..%2F..%2Fsprites%2F123.png%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0Aloop()%0A%20%20for%20k%2C%20v%20in%20currentProject%0A%20%20%20%20%26__%7Bk%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20background-image%20v%0A%0A.class%0A%20loop())